# Remove all <noscript> tags and content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, noscript

looking for a jQuery solution to remove/empty the contents of all  tags on an html page - including the  tag in the head... Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: Tried .empty and .remove - neither seem to work. Have added a class name to the contents of the <noscript> in the body, then used .remove() to sort that - but cant seem to target the <noscript> tag / element in the head to remove it...

Comment: You want to remove `<noscript>` ***IF*** scripting is enabled.?

Comment: atmd - yep, just for the sake of tidy code

Answer (score 1):

```js
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

          $("noscript").remove();

        }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: That removes the <noscript> elements from the body, but what about the head?

Comment: Why would you put a <noscript> tag in your head, it doesnt make sense there? Probably not even allowed there.

Comment: To add in some custom CSS for when JS is disabled - not invalid as far as I am aware?